# Passing a 2d array to a class through multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

My program creates a class "MyArray"

```
class MyArray{
    int[][] arr={{14,15,16},{11,12,13}};
}
```

And another class "Add_Thread"

```
class Add_Thread implements Runnable {

private final Matrix RES;
int row;
Thread t;
MyArray arr=new MyArray();

public Add_Thread(Matrix RES,int row) {
    this.RES = RES;
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
    this.row = row;
}

public void run() {
    synchronized(arr){
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.arr[0].length; i++) {
     RES.push(arr.arr[row][i]);   
    }
  }
}
}
```

which takes value from "MyArray" and pushes it to another class "Matrix"

```
class Matrix {

final int[][] res_matrix;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
private int k = 0;
private int l = 0;

public Matrix(int i, int j) {
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    res_matrix = new int[i][j];
}

public synchronized void push(int element) {

    int pos1 = k;
    int pos2 = l;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ResultantMatrix.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    res_matrix[pos1][pos2] = element;
    k++;
    l++;
}
}
```

it stores the value and send it to the main() function

```
public class Array_demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matrix res = new Matrix(2, 3);
    Add_Thread add=new Add_Thread(res, 0);
    Add_Thread add2=new Add_Thread(res, 1);
    for(int i=0;i<res.res_matrix.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<res.res_matrix[0].length;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(res.res_matrix[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

But i'm getting error in **void push()** method and **res_matrix[pos1][pos2]=element**. I'm new to thread so it would be great if my errors are broadly explained.

Output

```
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at threading.Matrix.push(Push.java:34)
at threading.Add_Thread.run(Push.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at threading.Matrix.push(Push.java:34)
    at threading.Add_Thread.run(Push.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Are you going to share the error message with us?  If it's a runtime exception be sure to include the complete stack trace. [edit] your post, do not reply in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the code:

`for (int i = 0; i < arr.arr[0].length; i++) {...}`

produces 3 loops, and in each loop you call `Matrix.push(...)`, so `push` is called three times.

In the `push` method, you increase the index `k` at every call; it starts with 0, after the first call is 1, after the second call is 2.

When you call `push` the third time, `k` holds the value of 2 and since it is assigned to the variable `pos1`, when you call:

`res_matrix[pos1][pos2] = element;`

you get the error:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2`

because the `res_matrix` array has dimension 2x3.